# Mobx-react doesnt play nicely with webpack and typescript - 'observer' is not exported member error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, webpack, mobx

In my .tsx file I import observer like that:

`import { observer } from "mobx-react"`

and am getting error:

```
ERROR in ./src/components/AppHeader/AppHeader.tsx
[tsl] ERROR in (...)AppHeader/AppHeader.tsx(2,10)
      TS2305: Module '"mobx-react"' has no exported member 'observer'.
```

`Mobx-react` obviously HAS `observer` and does export it. 
Am using `ts-loader` to manage `ts` and `tsx` files in webpack and this is my `tsconfig.json`.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "module": "esnext",
    "target": "es5",
    "jsx": "react",    
    "baseUrl": "./react/src",
    "lib": ["es2017", "dom"],
    "sourceMap": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "build",
    "scripts",
    "acceptance-tests",
    "webpack",
    "jest",
    "src/setupTests.ts"
  ]
}
```

Project has been bootstraped with `react-create-app` and has been ejected long time ago. It works just fine without TS support and now when I try to introduce TS into it, its literal nightmare.

Comment: Can you publish a repository that reproduces the problem (after removing any confidential information)?

Comment: Unfortunately I can not. I can try to remove 99% of files, leave literally 5 of them, see if it s reproducing and than post it here. 
It will take me some time (probably not today) but will get back to you.
Thanks!